# scale_x_continuous() and scale_x_discrete() not working in R

Tags: r

I wanted to break the x-axis of my histogram into 31 units. So I used the code using qplot():

```
qplot(x = dob_day, data = pf) +
  scale_x_discrete( breaks = 1:31)
```

And using ggplot():

```
ggplot(data = pf, aes(x = dob_day)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:31)
```

But either of the code does not update the plot. Instead the console shows

```
scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:31)
ggproto object: Class ScaleDiscretePosition, ScaleDiscrete, Scale>
aesthetics: x xmin xmax xend
break_info: function
break_positions: function
breaks: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 ...
call: call
clone: function
dimension: function
drop: TRUE
expand: waiver
get_breaks: function
get_breaks_minor: function
get_labels: function
get_limits: function
guide: none
is_discrete: function
is_empty: function
labels: waiver
limits: NULL
map: function
map_df: function
na.value: NA
name: waiver
palette: function
range: <ggproto object: Class RangeDiscrete, Range>
    range: NULL
    reset: function
    train: function
    super:  <ggproto object: Class RangeDiscrete, Range>
range_c: <ggproto object: Class RangeContinuous, Range>
    range: NULL
    reset: function
    train: function
    super:  <ggproto object: Class RangeContinuous, Range>
reset: function
scale_name: position_d
train: function
train_df: function
transform: function
transform_df: function
super:  <ggproto object: Class ScaleDiscretePosition, ScaleDiscrete, Scale>
```

Same happens with scale_x_continuous() where the console shows:

```
> scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 7, 1), limits = c(0, 7))
<ScaleContinuousPosition>
Range:  
Limits:    0 --    7
```

Comment: I do not believe you. `ggplot(data = pf, aes(x = dob_day)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:31)` does not give this output. There is something you are not telling us. Please provide a reproducible example. (What you show in the end is something else. There you don't add the scale to the plot using `+`.)

Comment: Right... `scale_*()` functions return a `ggproto` object that is useless by itself (in most cases). The output you're getting is what happens if you just run the `scale_*()` function by itself. You need to add it to a plot to be useful.

Comment: @Roland, believe me or not, this is what is happening. I tried to run the same code in RMD and its working !!

Comment: Have you redefined +? Does this still happen after restarting R?

Answer (score 1):

Make it reproducible. the console comes up with that output when you run the scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 7, 1), limits = c(0, 7)) without apllying it to something. Try this:

```
   gg <- ggplot(data = pf, aes(x = dob_day)) 
   gg <- gg +  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
           scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:31)
```

Comment: Not working !! But the same code is working in RMD !!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I forgot to add the '+' before scale_x_discrete. Adding the '+' fixed it.

Comment: The OP has  '+' before scale_x_discrete.